# shows an error message cannot solve symbol 'SEND_SMS'

Tags: android

i added some uses permission in the manifest file and in the mainactivity checks the permissions then it will shows an error message cannot solve symbol 'SEND_SMS'. How can 'i solve this?

The manifest line is:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Can you show us the line from the Manifest?

Comment: Add manifest code

Comment: this is my manifest file  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> and error shows in this line int permissionSendMessage= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have

`android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;`

instead of

`Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS`

the end result

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//task
}
```